# Searching duplicate entries in JTable depending on multiple columns

Tags: java, jtable, multiple-columns

Im still very new to java and just learned to work with JTables. When checking for duplicates in a JTable, I used this method for checking only one Column for my keyword:

```
private boolean duplicateEntry(String entry, JTable table, int column)
{       
    System.out.print("Duplicate check for "+entry+"...");
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        String found = table.getValueAt(i, column).toString();
        if (found.equals(entry))
        {
            System.out.println(" already in db!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("no entry found!");
    return false;
}
```

I'm now trying to get it to work for a more complex duplicate check: I want to check if the found row is identical in every column. To make it more clear the table looks like this:

| firstname | lastname | nationality | state |

---

If this is is my existing entry:

| John | Smith | German | Texas |

I want my duplicate check to return only true if all columns of the new row have the same values as the existing one.

---

So if wanted to add | John | Smith | **Polish** | Texas | -> check should return **false**

---

So if wanted to add | John | Smith | German | Texas | -> check should return **true**

---

I got it working with the following code, but it feels sloppy and inefficient:

*hCol* is the index of the table's column

```
priavte boolean duplicateEntryComplex(JTable table, String vMatch, int vCol, ArrayList<String> hMatch, int[] hCol)
{
    //search for matching rows (vertical)
    System.out.print("Duplicate check for "+vMatch+"...");

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        String found = table.getValueAt(i, vCol).toString();
        if (found.contains(vMatch))
        {
            // search inside found row (horizontal)
            int cols = hCol.length;
            ArrayList<Boolean> check = new ArrayList<Boolean>();                
            for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
            {
                boolean match = false;
                String searchFor2 = hMatch.get(r);
                String found2 = table.getValueAt(i, hCol[r]).toString();
                if (found2.contains(searchFor2))
                {
                    match = true;
                }
                // add result for current column to ArrayList
                check.add(match);                   
            }
            for (int x= 0; x < check.size(); x++)
            {
                if (check.get(x) == false)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (x == check.size()-1) // if all field were identical
                {
                    System.out.println(" already in db!");
                    return true;
                }
            }               
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" no duplicates found!");
    return false;
}
```

So my question is, if there is a more correct and efficient way to do this.

Comment: firstname , lastname , nationality and state  all are same for me and my friend who is sitting next to me.

Comment: @vels4j I editted my example to make it clearer.

Comment: @pogroboron You should try to create a custom TableModel and make the duplicate check inside of it.
So that you can allow or not the duplicated row to get in the table

Comment: This question can be closed: I found a smart solution by using Java 8 **Predicates**.